# Facebook Page category

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, programmers-notepad

I have a page with my own name. And I am a programmer. Now I wanna know what will be the page category of the Facebook page of a programmer? I can't understand? Would anyone please help me? I will be very grateful to you.